# How to display data according to the user information

Tags: php, mysql

I have two sql tables for user login, store and retrieve data according to the user ID.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM users u JOIN requests r ON (r.uid = u.id) WHERE r.request_id = ?");
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO NO NO, DON't DO THAT!!! You'll be hacked so easy!

use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [prepare statement](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

```
SELECT r.*,u.* FROM users u JOIN requests r ON (r.uid = u.id) WHERE r.request_id = ?
```

(you miss the space between the * and FROM)

It looks that you are not using OOP, I highly recommend you to take a fast tutorial to learn the basic about OOP, or if you have time and want to learn I will tell you to use some king of framework as Codeigni.ter or CakePHP to learn a lot about class and functions

Comment: He's probably just messing around not in production

Comment: @RPM I think he's, anyway I think he should do the things right and learn the "new" way to do the things.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't wanna use PDO or prepare statement, please prepare & filter the SQL statements and the variables. Never trust any userinput!

see http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php